# API Console for Maps For Businesses

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api-console

Is there a way to use the API Console instead of the Enterprise portal of Google Maps for Business to check my quotas and billable limits?

I created a project with the same account i use to enter the enterprise portal but im not sure they are both linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just FYI, all new projects renewed or created after january 1st of 2016 are using the developer console which is much simpler than the old site.

Answer (score 4):

Maps for Work (Enterprise) billing and quotas are available in the API Console only for the Google Places API, the Geolocation API, the Roads API, Maps SDKs for Android and iOS.

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/previous-faq#google_maps_api_services